# How to include the Localize module in Playground online

Tags: nativescript-angular

I am trying to include the `Localize` module in the online version of the `Playground`, but I got the below error:

> Cannot find module 'nativescript-localize/angular'.

Is it possible to do this online?

Answer (score 0):

The Playground still uses Nativescript 6. The playground is still being updated to be compatible with Nativescript 7.

You will get the following error when trying to add the Nativescript 7 package "@nativescript/localize/angular" on the Playground:
[image]

If you are using Nativescript 6, you can add the nativescript package "nativescript-localize" using this tutorial:
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2018/03/02/playground-plugins

1. Click the plus icon on the playground:
   [image]
2. Add the package "nativescript-localize"
   [image]
3. As you can see, no errors:
   [image]